# Setting up a proxy in AWS that adds a simple HTTP header to client requests

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, proxy, http-headers

I would want to set up a simple proxy in Amazon Web Services that, in addition to acting as a proxy between the client and server, adds a simple (fixed) HTTP header to every client request before sending them to server.

I already looked at the most promising http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront which, however, doesn't seem to allow adding headers. The other but rather inconvenient option would be setting up a new EC2 (or BeansTalk) service to do the proxying work, but this feels like overkill for such a simple task, and additionally would need ELB/AutoScaling setup to ensure availability.

Is there any simple high-level way to get this done without falling back to setting up custom servers or services?

Comment: There may be a way to accomplish what you want, but the question needs clarification... if the header is fixed (static), why do you need it added?  What's the header?  What is the end result you're wanting to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your own nginx instance and you can add a custom header to every request with this option:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header

Unfortunately Cloudfront does not support adding headers.

I would deploy cloudfront anyway. You can set the origin server as your nginx on a ec2 instance. Data transfer between cloudfront and ec2 is free:

> With Amazon CloudFront, you can use an AWS origin (e.g., Amazon S3,
>   Amazon EC2, Elastic Load Balancing, etc.) or your own origin servers
>   to store the original, definitive versions of your files. If you are
>   using an AWS origin, effective December 1, 2014, data transferred from
>   origin to edge locations (Amazon CloudFront "origin fetches") will be
>   free of charge. This applies to data transfer from all AWS regions to
>   all global CloudFront edge locations. Data Transfer out of Amazon
>   CloudFront to your origin server will be billed at the “Regional Data
>   Transfer Out to Origin” rates listed above. Pricing for all AWS
>   services is available here.